# Is there a javascript physic engine can simulate polygons in gravity?

Tags: javascript, physics-engine

Like [Google Gravity](http://mrdoob.com/projects/chromeexperiments/google_gravity/). The images are not only act as points but rectangles. They are rotated when I drag-drop them.

I saw [jPhysics](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jphysics) plugin but it can't simulate rotate.

I don't know how to drag thing with [Box2D-js](http://box2d-js.sourceforge.net/index2.html).

Is there a complete lib? or a tutorial which help me to implement by myself?

(What all I want is: drap-droping and rotating.)

Comment: Look at box2d more thats what google gravity uses. Also check out the source of google gravity as it has what you are looking for (drag, rotate), Im pretty sure mr. doob has a post mortem as well on it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a newer port of box2d to JS called Box2dWeb at http://code.google.com/p/box2dweb/ which seems cleaner than box2d-js (doesn't require a bazillion includes, for one thing) and is ported from a newer version of box2d. There is great example code in the source of http://www.tornadoentertainment.de/Box2dWeb/demo/demo.html?c1 which demonstrates the dragging behavior you want (rotation should be easy to add).